# FosOauthServerBundle Propel BaseClient not found

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, propel, fosoauthserverbundle

I'm using doctrine orm but somehow I get an error that the propel BaseClient is not found (a class usually autogenerated by propel).
Either it's a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

```
fos_oauth_server:
    db_driver:           orm
    client_class:        Diligentia\OAuthBundle\Entity\Client
    access_token_class:  Diligentia\OAuthBundle\Entity\AccessToken
    refresh_token_class: Diligentia\OAuthBundle\Entity\RefreshToken
    auth_code_class:     Diligentia\OAuthBundle\Entity\AuthCode
    service:
        user_provider: fos_user.user_manager
```

The error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Propel\om\BaseClient' not found in /var/www/redwood/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle/Propel/Client.php on line 19

Fatal error: Class 'FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Propel\om\BaseClient' not found in /var/www/redwood/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle/Propel/Client.php on line 19
Segmentation fault
```

Seems to me it shouldn't even attempt to load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

predis wasn't installed with composer causing my caching not to work.
Due to that the User Bundle was unable to obtain which db driver I used and putting propel as default causing the unrelated error and my inability to find the issue for a long time.